# How to do password reset without any verfication

Tags: laravel, api

I am developing an app.App login is through phone number and is will show password reset only if the phone is verified in client side and after than reset password request occur.So in simple i want to reset password of user without any verification in backend

Comment: `the phone is verified in client side` _Do not trust the client_.

Comment: I have used OTP code to verify the phone

Answer (score 0):

so i can safely assume phone number verification is done by OTP? like when they request for password change the server will send a sms to the registered users phone number to verify that it is the actual phone number holder who is requesting for password change.

but you still have to verify that the OTP number provided by the user matches with the one generate from backend and then only change the user password.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$user = User::where('contact', $request->contact)
if($request->otp == $user->reset_otp)
{
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();
}
```